# Parsing a string into a list by column to mimic a table in Java, using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, list, parsing

**What I have:**

I have a string that looks like this

```
"a, b, c\nd, e, f\ng, h, i"
```

each new line represents a new row, each comma represents a different column

**What I want to do:**

I'm trying to pass this into a list so that it looks like this:

```
[ [a,d,g], [b,e,h], [c,f,i] ]
```

that way it mimics a table, a table that would look like this:

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h   i
```

In other words, I'm making a list of each column.

**What I know how to do:**

I know if I were making a list of rows I could do this:

```
String rows[]= text.split("\\r?\\n");
```

and end up with an array of rows:

```
{"a, b, c", "d, e, f", "g, h, i"}
```

and then format each string as a list later but how would I accomplish what I want stated above using a regex with 1 or no loop? I'm trying for `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)` algorithm where `n` is the number of rows. Thank you :)

**What I'm currently doing:**

```
 //This is pseudocode so it's not valid

 new list of list called columnList
 String rows[]= text.split("\\r?\\n");
 for each row in rows:
     i=0
     new splitRow = row split by comma
     for each element in splitRow:
         columnList(i).add(element)
         i++
```

This is the algorithm I came up with but it's really slow and requires nested loops. I don't think it's very efficient.

**Further Info:**

I'm doing all this in Java

I can't use any Hash structures so no dictionaries sadly

Sorry if my formatting is oddly formal, I've had problems communicating my questions clearly in the past.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh yes, sorry, i'll edit that now

Comment: @shmosel I'll google Guava now, also I should probably mention, the input I gave is an example, a lot of my tests are similar but some have a different number of rows and columns, I can't hardcode in `3`

Comment: @shmosel nevermind that last part, I could probably find the length somehow

Answer (score 0):

I think the steps should be:

1. Replace "\n" in the original String
2. Split the "," to the String[]
3. Convert one dimension array to two dimension array.

Something looks like:

```
        String s = "a, b, c\nd, e, f\ng, h, i";
        String[] elements = s.replace("\n", ",").split(",");
        String[][] table = new String[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                table[i][j] = elements[(j * 3) + i];
            }
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I like your method but I'm trying to do this without nested loops if possible. I'm trying to get an O(n) situation

Answer (score 0):

Use your solution with the nested loops.  If you're worried that it isn't O(n), don't be: it **is** O(n).  The time it takes will always be exactly proportional to the number of input elements.

**Concrete example #1**: In your 3-row, 3-column input, you have 9 elements total.  The outer loop gets executed 3 times.  The inner loop executes 3 times for each of those, a total of 9 times.  9 inputs = 9 inner loop executions.

**Concrete example #2**: Now let's say you give it a 5-row, 7-column input.  You have 35 items total.  The outer loop executes five times.  The inner loop execute seven times for each of those, a total of 5x7=35 times.  35 inputs = 35 inner loop executions.

**Abstract**: How about an input of *r* rows by *c* columns?  Total input items = *r* x *c*.  Outer loop executes *r* times, inner loop executes *c* times for each of those.  Thus, *r* x *c* total inner loop iterations.  *r* x *c* input items = *r* x *c* inner loop iterations.

Whatever the total number of input elements, the inner loop executes exactly that many times.  That is virtually the *definition* of **O(n)**.

Comment: Yeah but in my situation, n is the number of rows. Sorry I wasn't clear on that, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
    String text = "a, b, c\nd, e, f\ng, h, i";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)(?:\r?\n|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    List<List<String>> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    while (matcher.find()){
        List<String> row = Splitter.on(",").trimResults().splitToList(matcher.group(1));
        result.add(row);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

remember import:

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out now

Comment: Hey, I tried your code, looks like it outputs in rows but I asked for columns, thank you though